# Find which schema table belongs to in sql developer?

Tags: sql-server, metadata, information-schema

I am using sql server connections in sql developer with the help of a plug-in...

Now my question is I have a list of tables which belong to sql server connections but I don't have the information on, which table belongs to which schema?

I have tried using the script

select owner, table_name 
 from all_tables 
 where table_name like 'xxxxxxxx%';

but it didn't work out, can any one please help out on this???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: try `sys.tables` or `information_schema.tables`

Comment: you mean in place of all_tables or any where else?

Comment: yes `select owner, table_name from all_tables where sys.tables like 'xxxxxxxx%'; `

Comment: but that is throwing an error "invalid object name all_tables"

Comment: Mybad, `select * from  sys.tables where name like 'xxxxxxxx%'`

Comment: `all_tables` is Oracle stuff for Sql Server you need to use `sys.tables`

Comment: Hi every one I got the desired result..first use select * from sys.tables where name like 'xxxxxxxx%' query to get schema id and using schema id write select * from sys.schemas where schema_id=x; to get the schema name...

Answer (score 2):

```
Select schema_name (schema_id), name 
from sys.tables 
where name like 'your pattern'
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ben Thul has an answer that is absolutely fine.

This is just an alternative using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (both of which essentially use sys.objects under the hood):

```
SELECT
    t.TABLE_CATALOG
    ,t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,t.TABLE_NAME
    ,t.TABLE_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%<YOUTABLE>%'
```

Comment: I use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` all the time, what a great feature.